# Admin grids are blank after installation of fresh Magento 2.1

Tags: magento2, admin, grid, upgrade, installation

I have recently installed `Magento 2.1`.

After and run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`.

I have cleared all cache `rm -rf var/cache/*`,`rm -rf var/page_cache/*`

And logged in to admin panel i have checked their is no data populating in `Catalog`,`Sales`,`Pages`,`Blocks` event each grids are blank.

I had checked console and found that their some JavaScript errors are displaying.

```
    Error parsing header X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block, 1; mode=block: expected semicolon at character position 14. The default protections will be applied.
    jquery-migrate.js:21 JQMIGRATE: Logging is active
    VM441:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'provider' of undefined(anonymous function) @ VM441:1template @ template.js:43render @ template.js:97iterate @ template.js:174_.each._.forEach @ underscore.js:150iterate @ template.js:176_.each._.forEach @ underscore.js:150template @ template.js:161initConfig @ class.js:88initialize @ class.js:69_super @ wrapper.js:106initialize @ element.js:89(anonymous function) @ wrapper.js:109constr @ class.js:48initComponent @ layout.js:64fire @ jquery.js:3099fireWith @ jquery.js:3211deferred.(anonymous function) @ jquery.js:3301fire @ jquery.js:3099fireWith @ jquery.js:3211deferred.(anonymous function) @ jquery.js:3301(anonymous function) @ layout.js:57execCb @ require.js:1650check @ require.js:866(anonymous function) @ require.js:1113(anonymous function) @ require.js:132(anonymous function) @ require.js:1156each @ require.js:57emit @ require.js:1155check @ require.js:917enable @ require.js:1143init @ require.js:774callGetModule @ require.js:1170completeLoad @ require.js:1544onScriptLoad @ require.js:1671
    require.js:1895 GET http://magento2.amanweb.in/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/rjsResolver.js req.load @ require.js:1895load @ require.js:1639load @ require.js:820fetch @ require.js:810check @ require.js:840enable @ require.js:1143enable @ require.js:1511(anonymous function) @ require.js:1128(anonymous function) @ require.js:132each @ require.js:57enable @ require.js:1090init @ require.js:774callGetModule @ require.js:1170completeLoad @ require.js:1544onScriptLoad @ require.js:1671
    require.js:166 Uncaught Error: Script error for: rjsResolver
    http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
```

I am getting same issue after upgrade from `Magento 2.0.7` to `Magento 2.1.0`

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Try to delete all old static contents and re-run static content.

Comment: aside from the var/cache/* and page_cache try also removing pub/static/*

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh i have deleted all static content re run deploy command issue is same.

Comment: @camdixon i have applied your suggested step and run deploy command but still issue is same.

Comment: @AmanAlam I would now then open a ticket on github under issues for magento 2 to potentially get more help.  Could be a bug especially because 2.1 is so new?

Comment: @camdixon have already opened a ticket in github for magento 2 https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5421

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this problem with by applying below mentioned solution.

Removed all content in from below mentioned folders:

```
var/cache
var/page_cache
var/generation
pub/static
```

And open magento admin in private browser. Its resolved.